# VB.NET webbrowser not working anymore with google maps

Tags: vb.net, google-maps, google-api

So I have this legacy program that has been running forever without any problems (showing a map with custom markers and functionallities), and suddenly this week the webbrowser component stopped working. First I get this script error message:

[image: script error]

and when I say "yes" I get the next message:

[image: unsupported browser]

I'm already using this in the html to no avail:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
```

Actually, this is the entire html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
     <style type="text/css">
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #gmap {
        height: 100%;
      }
     </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&sensor=false&callback=initMap"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
          //Use window.X instead of var X to make a variable globally available 
          window.markers = new Array();
          window.marker_data = [[41.9205558333333,0.1881085,'TXT1','ICONPATH'],[41.68436,-0.88455,'TXT2','ICONPATH']]
          window.gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), {
                zoom: 15,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(marker_data[0][0], marker_data[0][1]),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
          window.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          var newmarker, i;
          window.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          for (i = 0; i < marker_data.length; i++) {
              if (marker_data[0].length == 2) {
                  newmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: new google.maps.LatLng(marker_data[i][0], marker_data[i][1]),
                      map: gmap
                  });
              } else if (marker_data[0].length == 3) {
                  newmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: new google.maps.LatLng(marker_data[i][0], marker_data[i][1]),
                      map: gmap,
                      title: (marker_data[i][2])
                  });
              } else {
                  newmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: new google.maps.LatLng(marker_data[i][0], marker_data[i][1]),
                      map: gmap,
                      title: (marker_data[i][2]),
                      icon: (marker_data[i][3])
                  });
              }
            google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker, 'click', (function (newmarker, i) {
                return function () {
                    if (newmarker.title) {
                        infowindow.setContent(newmarker.title);
                        infowindow.open(gmap, newmarker);
                    }
                    gmap.setCenter(newmarker.getPosition());
                    // Calling functions written in the windows form
                    //window.external.showVbHelloWorld();
                    //window.external.getMarkerDataFromJavascript(newmarker.title,i);
                    window.external.selectGVRow(newmarker.title);
                }
            })(newmarker, i));
            markers[i] = newmarker;
            console.log('maker' + i + ': ' + markers[i].getPosition());
            bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
          }

          google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(gmap, 'idle', function () {
              gmap.fitBounds(bounds);
              gmap.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
              window.external.showWarningFrontera();
          });

        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        
        
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Function triggered from the WF with no arguments
        function showJavascriptHelloWorld() {
            alert("Hello world in HTML from WF");
        }
     </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        // Function triggered from the WF with a String argument
        function focusMarkerFromIdx(idx) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[idx], 'click');
        }
        function focusMarkerFromName(name) {
            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                if (markers[i].title == name) {
                    gmap.setCenter(markers[i].getPosition());
                    infowindow.setContent(markers[i].title);
                    infowindow.open(gmap, markers[i]);
                }
            } 
        }
        function getMapZoom() {
            return gmap.getZoom();
        }
        function resetZoom() {
            gmap.fitBounds(bounds);
            gmap.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
        }
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="gmap"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried modifying registry as explained [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version), but it does not work.
Am I missing something or it is just that google apis stopped supporting legacy browsers? Is there any workaround? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you replace the old WebBrowser Control with the new [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/)

Answer (score 3):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport

Add `&v=3.47` to your script tag to keep the app working until August 2022.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap&v=3.47"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, that will give me some oxygen until august!